# Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration on Apache 2.4

Tags: python-3.5, django-1.8, apache2.4

I know a lot of post has this issue but nothing works quite well on my end on the Apache 2.4 version

Every time I try to run "sudo service apache2 restart"
It throws this error

Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.

I included a 'httpd.conf' on my apache.conf

And below is my configuration on the 'httpd.conf':

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/people/people/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/people:/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Alias /media/ /var/www/people/media/
Alias /staic/ /var/www/people/staic/

<Directory /var/www/people/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/people/media>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load (LoadModule) mod_wsgi to use it -- it's not part of the core apache distribution or the vanilla httpd/apache2 packages of most linux distributions.  Find the add-on and enable it.